# Compare multiple string in case shell script

Tags: shell-script, string, case

I am comparing string in case statement as below :
 input variable can be D P KL ...

```
case $input in
      D|P|Q|L1|L2)
         val="Hello";;
      DD|DE|DF|CA)
          val="Hi" ;;
      MM|KL||TK|SZ)
         val="Bye" ;;
         echo $input
```

input variable not printing anything..

Comment: What is the value in `$input`?  Also, the `case` statement is partial (not closed by `esac`), and you're not using `$val` anywhere.

Comment: Should always be `case "$input"`. It seems to me that the esac is missing. Or shall `$input` be printed only in the last case? And why `$input` and not `$val`? Strange code...

Comment: @HaukeLaging Quoting `$input` in the `case` statement is good practice, but actually not necessary. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary  (note, I always quote the expansion in `case` statements)

Comment: yeah ..it was by mistake i didnot esac

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two main issues in you script:

1. The `case` statement is not closed by `esac`.
2. The third pattern contains `||` which is a syntax error in most Bourne-like shells (use `''` or `""` or an expansion that resolves to an empty value to match on the empty string portably)

It's unclear what your script is actually doing, so I'm speculating a bit and wrote this:

```
#!/bin/sh

input="$1"

case "$input" in
      D|P|Q|L1|L2)
          val='Hello' ;;
      DD|DE|DF|CA)
          val='Hi' ;;
      MM|KL|""|TK|SZ)
          val='Bye' ;;
      *)
          echo 'error' >&2
          exit 1
esac

printf 'input was "%s", val is "%s"\n' "$input" "$val"
```

Testing it:

```
$ ./script.sh D
input was "D", val is "Hello"

$ ./script.sh MM
input was "MM", val is "Bye"

$ ./script.sh BOO
error
```